# Crop face from image

Tags: android, xamarin, google-vision

So I have been trying to crop the face from image taken in `Xamarin.Android`. I am using `Google Vision` to detect the Faces and its coordinates. The canvas around the face is drawn properly but unable to crop the image properly, using the following piece of code.

```
   Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(rotatedBmp, x,y,w,h);
```

What should be the values of x,y,w,h for cropping the image properly ?

For now I have used x = face.Position().X , y= face.Position().Y, w= face.Width, h= face.Height

Comment: that appears to be correct.

Comment: What's the error youre facing

Comment: @Sameer It is not cropping the right region of face

Comment: And the position you get is relative to what? Refer to https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/photo-demo/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/photo/FaceView.java which shows how to draw face annotations